# VS 2013 update 3 RTM fails 0x80004002 errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installation, updates

Uses: Windows 7 pro sp1; VS 2013 Pro;

I tried to install VS 2013 update 3 but it fails without neither throwing a message or a specifying a reason. The log specifies as:

> [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]e000: Error 0x80004002: Failed to run
>   per-user mode.  [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i007: Exit code:
>   0x80004002, restarting: No

The Entire Log:

> [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i001: Burn v3.7.3117.0, Windows v6.1
>   (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path: D:\Software\IDE\VS
>   2013\Update\vs2013.3\VS2013.3.exe, cmdline: '-burn.unelevated
>   BurnPipe.{B43BB71C-5897-420E-9EDD-686F07FE192D}
>   {55B523A4-48FF-4C01-B455-D5F599912969} 18624'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'EditionDisplayName' to value '#loc.vsupdatededitiondisplayname'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'FactorMsi' to value '1.3' [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000:
>   Initializing numeric variable 'MoreLanguageFwlinkId' to value '376932'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'PrivacyAgreementFwlinkId' to value '376910'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'PrivacyStatementFwlinkId' to value '376910'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'MinOsLevelFwlinkId' to value '376920'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'SolutionFwlinkId' to value '376911'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'HelpFwlinkId' to value '376912' [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000:
>   Initializing numeric variable 'IE10FwlinkId' to value '376914'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'WinBlueFwlinkId' to value '376917'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'SHA256BlockFwlinkId' to value '376918'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'Win81PreRelBlockFwlinkId' to value '376916'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'NetfxProductVersion' to value '4.5.30723'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'ProfessionalVSVersion' to value '11.0.50727'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'BaselineBundleVersion' to value '12.0.21005'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'FirstSlipstreamBundleVersion' to value '12.0.21006'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'ProductKey' to value 'VVXKCDCCWD3B29PWQK2C3GYD7'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_chs' to value 'true'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_cht' to value 'true'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_csy' to value 'true'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_deu' to value 'true'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_esn' to value 'true'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_fra' to value 'true'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_ita' to value 'true'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_jpn' to value 'true'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_kor' to value 'true'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_plk' to value 'true'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_ptb' to value 'true'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_rus' to value 'true'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_trk' to value 'true'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'Win8Dev_Dev11Path' to value '[ProgramFilesFolder]Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 11.0\' [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing
>   string variable 'Dev11_UT_Path' to value
>   '[ProgramFilesFolder]Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'WinSDK_Common_KitsRootPath' to value '[ProgramFilesFolder]Windows
>   Kits\8.0\' [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string
>   variable 'Dev11_VC_Path' to value '[ProgramFilesFolder]Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 11.0\' [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000:
>   Initializing numeric variable 'IsChainingx64VSTODT' to value '1'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'IsChainingx86VSTODT' to value '1'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'Include_WindowsPhoneAppxEmulator' to value 'true'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Setting string variable
>   'WixBundleLog' to value
>   'D:\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vsupdate_KB2829760_20141112183944.log'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Setting string variable
>   'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'D:\Software\IDE\VS
>   2013\Update\vs2013.3\VS2013.3.exe'
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Setting string variable
>   'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'D:\Software\IDE\VS
>   2013\Update\vs2013.3\' [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:44]i000: Setting
>   string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Visual Studio 2013 Update 3
>   (KB2829760)' [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i000: Loading managed
>   bootstrapper application. [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]e000: Error
>   0x80004002: Failed to create the managed bootstrapper application.
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]e000: Error 0x80004002: Failed to
>   create UX. [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]e000: Error 0x80004002:
>   Failed to load UX. [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]e000: Error
>   0x80004002: Failed while running 
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable: BaselineBundleVersion
>   = 12.0.21005 [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable: Dev11_UT_Path = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable: Dev11_VC_Path =
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable: EditionDisplayName =
>
> ## loc.vsupdatededitiondisplayname [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable: FactorMsi = 1.3 [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410:
>
> Variable: FirstSlipstreamBundleVersion = 12.0.21006
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable: HelpFwlinkId = 376912
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable: IE10FwlinkId = 376914
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable:
>   Include_WindowsPhoneAppxEmulator = true
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable: IsChainingx64VSTODT =
>   1 [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable: IsChainingx86VSTODT
>   = 1 [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable: MinOsLevelFwlinkId = 376920 [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable: MoreLanguageFwlinkId = 376932 [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410:
>   Variable: NetfxProductVersion = 4.5.30723
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable:
>   PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_chs = true
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable:
>   PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_cht = true
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable:
>   PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_csy = true
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable:
>   PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_deu = true
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable:
>   PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_esn = true
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable:
>   PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_fra = true
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable:
>   PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_ita = true
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable:
>   PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_jpn = true
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable:
>   PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_kor = true
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable:
>   PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_plk = true
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable:
>   PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_ptb = true
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable:
>   PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_rus = true
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable:
>   PerfToolsRES_LangRelevant_trk = true
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable:
>   PrivacyAgreementFwlinkId = 376910
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable:
>   PrivacyStatementFwlinkId = 376910
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable: ProductKey =
>   VVXKCDCCWD3B29PWQK2C3GYD7 [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410:
>   Variable: ProfessionalVSVersion = 11.0.50727
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable: ProgramFilesFolder =
>   C:\Program Files\ [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable:
>   SHA256BlockFwlinkId = 376918 [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410:
>   Variable: SolutionFwlinkId = 376911
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable:
>   Win81PreRelBlockFwlinkId = 376916
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable: Win8Dev_Dev11Path =
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable: WinBlueFwlinkId =
>   376917 [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable:
>   WinSDK_Common_KitsRootPath = C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 5
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog =
>   D:\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vsupdate_KB2829760_20141112183944.log
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer
>   = Microsoft Corporation [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 (KB2829760)
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable:
>   WixBundleOriginalSource = D:\Software\IDE\VS
>   2013\Update\vs2013.3\VS2013.3.exe
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable:
>   WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder = D:\Software\IDE\VS
>   2013\Update\vs2013.3\ [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable:
>   WixBundleProviderKey = vsupdate_KB2829760
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag =
>   vsupdate_KB2829760,1033 [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i410:
>   Variable: WixBundleVersion = 12.0.30723.0
>   [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]e000: Error 0x80004002: Failed to run
>   per-user mode. [48AC:48B0][2014-11-12T18:39:45]i007: Exit code:
>   0x80004002, restarting: No

FYI, My VS Version:
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you are installing update 3? Update 4 was released 12 Nov. 2014.

Comment: I got the Update 4 yesterday and I experiencing the same thing as I did with Update 3. I am clueless here :(

Comment: Is it the web installer or iso

Comment: I  tried both, but same result for Update 3 and Update 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Create a new windows user account on the same machine
2. Run the install from the new user account (which, by default, will instal visual studio in such a way that it was available to all user accounts on the same machine)
3. Delete the new windows user account id

Comment: I did it different way, instead of my login user id which has local administrative privileges, I installed it from the Administrator account and it worked!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could be of some assistance